# Correct way to use tabs with several views in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm currently trying to create an Ionic 1 app that has a total of 4 tabs. Every tab has its own buttons that lead to new pages. As an example of my current implementation, I have one tab called 'tabs.group'. In this group there is a button to create a new group, which leads to a new state. That state also contains a button to a next screen to add members.

```
    .state('tabs.groups', {
        url: '/groups',
        views: {
            'groups-tab': {
                templateUrl: 'views/groups/groups.html',
                controller: 'GroupsController'
            }
        }
    })
            .state('tabs.creategroup', {
                url: '/creategroup',
                views: {
                    'groups-tab': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/groups/creategroup.html',
                        controller: 'GroupsController'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('tabs.addmembers', {
                url: '/addmembers',
                views: {
                    'groups-tab': {
                        templateUrl: 'views/groups/addmembers.html',
                        controller: 'GroupsController'
                    }
                },
                params: {
                    groupkey: null,
                    groupname: null
                }
            })
```

The issue is that when I click on a button in my 'tabs.group' tab view, I am redirected to the 'tabs.creategroup' but the tabs menu bar still stays visible. I have searched for a solution but it seems all that's possible is to manually add the class tabs-item-hide whenever the tabs should not be shown.

This however seems really buggy. Tabs appear back after some wait time, and are positioned on top of my content. On top of this, my  sometimes disappears when visiting a second view after a tab. This has made me question if I am going about this the correct way after all. Can anyone tell me what my routes should look like when I try to achieve this structure? I have not been able to find any clear examples when this seems such a common structure of an app Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a issue, change your code. You are still watching tabs menu bar because yours **.state** are calling it.

```
 .state('tabs.groups', {
        url: '/groups',
        views: {
            'groups-tab': {
                templateUrl: 'views/groups/groups.html',
                controller: 'GroupsController'
            }
        }
    })
            .state('creategroup', {
                url: '/creategroup',
                templateUrl: 'views/groups/creategroup.html',
                controller: 'GroupsController'
            })
            .state('addmembers', {
                url: '/addmembers',
                templateUrl: 'views/groups/addmembers.html',
                controller: 'GroupsController',
                params: {
                    groupkey: null,
                    groupname: null
                }
            })
```